# java чтение текстового файла, когда, какой класс использовать?

Tags: java, файлы, потоки-данных, io

Видите ли, есть много способов читать данные из текстового файла:
1) `FileInputStream`
2) `RandomAccessFile`
3) `Scanner`
4) `FileReader`
5) `DataInputStream`

И я немного запутался когда, что использовать.
Знаете ли вы какие-то источники о том каким образом все эти классы связаны, как все это устроено?
И какие классы подойдут лучше для работы именно с текстовими файлами.

Comment: Используй BufferedReader, в который запихивай FileReader. Если же отвечать на твой вопрос, то для символьных потоков лучше использовать Reader'ы, а для байтовых потоков InputStream'ы. В данном случае лучше использовать FileReader, а точнее завернуть его в BufferedReader, так как это даст большой буст к производительности

Comment: @NarasuOo Спасибо большое, все понятно